# How can i pass bash variable into groovy?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to write a jenkinsfile to run a job via pipeline. My requirement to pass a varriable's value from shell to groovy. My jenkinsfile is in grrovy language but i am using shell command somewhere.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please give us some code ? :)

Comment: Depending on your use case there's different ways of achieving that - and one of them was already posted by @rich-duncan. Please provide more details and the part of your Jenkinsfile you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

So, "a way" but perhaps not "the way" to do this would be to have the shell step write the value to a file:

```
sh 'echo "${NEEDED_VALUE} > needed.value.txt'
```

then pick that value up in groovy:

```
script {
  def neededValue = readFile('needed.value.txt')
  // do something with the value here
}
```

Comment: it's not working, as i am not able to run groovy commands inside script.

Comment: Post your pipeline

Comment: Please post your script or fragment